# Can database file be seen in a jailbreak device?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, resources, jailbreak

I wonder if a database file in resource directory `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("xxxx", ofType: "db")` can it be seen in a jailbreak device?

Some directories and files, such as document and library, can be seen via a program connecting with the jailbreak device. I'm considering if the contents of database file need to be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All app files are available to the user, jailbroken or not, either in the sandbox directories or in the .ipa.

What is not stated in the question is wether the db will be pre-populated during app creation and if so will it be read-only or allow additions/changes. A db in the resource directory is read-only and must be copied to a sandbox directory in order to be written to.

Encryption is an option to increase the work factor, that is make it harder obtain the db contents and discourage the curious by increasing the difficulty to obtain access.

The problem with encryption is that the key needs to be available to the app code and there is no secure way to have it available to the code and not also have it available to a determined and capable attacker. You need to define the attacker and the value of the data.

But as previously stated, increasing the work factor can provide meaningful security. The simplest way is to encrypt the db and place the key in the source code and try to make it non-obvious.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I may prefer to just make it harder to get the contents. Any suggestion about how to make the key non-obvious" in source code?

Comment: It is hard for an attacker to see the app's code, it is encrypted in the .ipa and decrypted for execution. If you have an attacker at that level there is little you can do. Define the attacker (from curious teen-ager, serious attacker to well funded government), the value of the data (to you, to the content owner, to the attacker) and the damage to the user and/or your reputation. What an attacker is willing to commit in $$.

Comment: It is hard for my level to stop any attacker. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access *all* files on a jailbroken device: yes, a user can see your database on a jailbroken device. But since it's in your bundle, all a user needs to see your file is the IPA.

Comment: I may prefer encryption for a better security. IPA represents the directory "appName.app" on a jailbroken device?

Comment: A [IPA file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension)) is an iOS application archive. Xcode can export these and iTunes can download these from the App Store or the device. So a normal user can easily get access to these, once (s)he bought the app.